# Jackson polymorphic deserialisation without using annotations

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I have an `Animal` class accepting a generic type parameter `T`, as shown below:

```
public class Animal<T> {
    private String type;
    private T details;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The type parameter can be `Dog` or `Cat`.

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private boolean goodBoy;

    // no-arg, all-args constructors, getters and setters
}

public class Cat {
    private String name;
    private boolean naughty;

    // no-arg, all-args constructors, getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to deserialise the following `JSON`.

```
{
    "type": "dog",
    "details": {
        "name": "Marley",
        "goodBoy": true
    }
}
```

However, when I deserialise, the field details always gets deserialised as a `LinkedHashMap` and not the particular implementation of the class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Animal<Dog> dog = new Animal<>();
    dog.setType("dog");
    dog.setDetails(new Dog("Marley", true));

    String dogJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(dog);
    Animal dogDeserialized = mapper.readValue(dogJson, Animal.class);

    // dogDeserialized's details is LinkedHashMap
}
```

I cannot change the above classes, and so can't use annotations on the field. Is there a way I can specify the list of classes which the `ObjectMapper` may deserialise the `details` field to ?

Note that the value of the `type` field is set to "dog" or "cat" for respective `Dog` or `Cat` classes.

Comment: Have you found any solution for your problem. Is one from two answers was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TypeReference` to specify the type to Deserialized

```
Animal<Dog> dogDeserialized = mapper.readValue(
    dogJson, new TypeReference<Animal<Dog>>() {});
```

Or instead of `Dog` and `Cat` you can have only one class with all the properties

```
public class AnimalDetails {

  private String name;
  private Boolean goodBoy;
  private Boolean naughty;

 }
```

And set ObjectMapper to ignore unknown properties in the JSON:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

So if it is `Dog` class `naughty` will be `null` and if it is `Cat` class `goodBoy` will be `null`

Comment: But what if I don't know beforehand if it's JSON for dog or cat. I want to be able to do this at runtime.

Comment: Is it not possible to use some sort of Mixin/ custom deserializer to do this ?

Comment: `Dog` and `Cat` have different variables, i would say custom deserializer is the best option @OneMoreError

Comment: How do you configure these custom deserializers ? Sorry, I am new to Jackson so any starting point will help a long way.

Comment: check my updated code @OneMoreError, custom deserializer is a long way

Comment: I cannot change the implementation of the classes. The classes provided here are just dummy placeholders. These classes are part of jar, which I cannot change.

Comment: so correct me if i'm wrong, do you want to know the `JSON` type first and then deserialize it into corresponding class @OneMoreError?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not change `POJO` model you need to implement custom deserialiser and handle types manually. Custom deserialiser could look like below:

```
class AnimalJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Animal> {

    private Map<String, Class> availableTypes = new HashMap<>();

    public AnimalJsonDeserializer() {
        availableTypes.put("cat", Cat.class);
        availableTypes.put("dog", Dog.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Animal deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode root = parser.readValueAsTree();
        JsonNode type = getProperty(parser, root, "type");

        Animal<Object> animal = new Animal<>();
        animal.setType(type.asText());

        Class<?> pojoClass = availableTypes.get(animal.getType());
        if (pojoClass == null) {
            throw new JsonMappingException(parser, "Class is not found for " + animal.getType());
        }

        JsonNode details = getProperty(parser, root, "details");
        animal.setDetails(parser.getCodec().treeToValue(details, pojoClass));

        return animal;
    }

    private JsonNode getProperty(JsonParser parser, ObjectNode root, String property) throws JsonMappingException {
        JsonNode value = root.get(property);
        if (value.isMissingNode() || value.isNull()) {
            throw new JsonMappingException(parser, "No " + property + " field!");
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

We need to use `SimpleModule` class and register deserialiser for `Animal` class. Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule animalModule = new SimpleModule();
        animalModule.addDeserializer(Animal.class, new AnimalJsonDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(animalModule);

        Animal<Dog> dog = new Animal<>();
        dog.setType("dog");
        dog.setDetails(new Dog("Marley", true));

        Animal<Cat> cat = new Animal<>();
        cat.setType("cat");
        cat.setDetails(new Cat("Tom", false));

        Animal<Dog> husky = new Animal<>();
        husky.setType("husky");
        husky.setDetails(new Dog("Sib", true));

        for (Animal animal : new Animal[]{dog, cat, husky}) {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(animal);
            System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
            System.out.println("Deserialized: " + mapper.readValue(json, Animal.class));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
JSON: {"type":"dog","details":{"name":"Marley","goodBoy":true}}
Deserialized: Animal{type='dog', details=Dog{name='Marley', goodBoy=true}}

JSON: {"type":"cat","details":{"name":"Tom","naughty":false}}
Deserialized: Animal{type='cat', details=Cat{name='Tom', naughty=false}}

JSON: {"type":"husky","details":{"name":"Sib","goodBoy":true}}
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class is not found for husky
 at [Source: (String)"{"type":"husky","details":{"name":"Sib","goodBoy":true}}"; line: 1, column: 56]
    at AnimalJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonApp.java:69)
    at AnimalJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonApp.java:50)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.celoxity.JsonApp.main(JsonApp.java:44)
```

### MixIn feature could be possible if you could change classes.

If you can not change source classes you can always use `Mix-in` feature which allows to create new interface with similar method and annotate all required classes appropriately. In your case we need to remove also `type` property which will be handled automatically by `Jackson`. Your example, after changes, could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Animal.class, AnimalMixIn.class);

        Animal<Dog> dog = new Animal<>();
        dog.setDetails(new Dog("Marley", true));

        String dogJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(dog);
        System.out.println(dogJson);
        Animal dogDeserialized = mapper.readValue(dogJson, Animal.class);
        System.out.println(dogDeserialized);
    }
}

interface AnimalMixIn {

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")})
    Object getDetails();
}

class Animal<T> {

    private T details;

    public T getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(T details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal{details=" + details + '}';
    }
}
```

`Cat` and `Dogs` classes stay the same. Above code prints:

```
{"details":{"name":"Marley","goodBoy":true},"type":"dog"}
Animal{details=Dog{name='Marley', goodBoy=true}}
```

See also:

- [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)
- [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)
- [Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568867/jackson-parse-json-with-unwraping-root-but-without-ability-to-set-jsonrootname)
- [What is equivalent code settings for @JSonIgnore annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939333/what-is-equivalent-code-settings-for-jsonignore-annotation)
- [Jackson JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757431/jackson-jsontypeinfo-as-external-property-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: Op stated that target classes are in an external jar and cannot be modified. therefore, type property cannot be removed

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, good point. I will remove my answer until I find something better which will work without changing source class. Good point. +1

Comment: 1) I am not OP 2) this topic is from 4 months ago, why bother?