# Spring Boot @JsonIgnore on entity, sometimes I want a property to be returned as Json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have an API I'm building using Spring Boot. The API will return recipes.

I have an @Entity which contains all of the properties for my recipes, including things such as the category, ingredients and the steps needed to make the recipe.

I have two API endpoints, once which returns a list of recipes (/recipes), and another which returns details on an individual recipe (/recipes/49).

My problem is that in the endpoint that lists recipes (/recipes) I don't want to return properties such as ingredients and steps, but I do want to return them in the endpoint which provided details on an individual recipe (/recipes/49). The problem is that using @JsonIgnore always removed the properties from ALL JSON responses, which is not what I need.

I've tried to do some research but can't seem to find a solution, and the only way I can think about doing this is to always loop through each recipe and populate some kind of response object which only has the necessary properties for the endpoint that they're being returned in, but this doesn't 'feel' right.

Is someone able to confirm how you would go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) details how to use `@JsonView` annotations and view classes to specify which fields to return from various endpoints.

Comment: While this at first glance looked like the perfect solution, it sadly doesn't work for me as my List of recipes is returned by the controller inside a custom api wrapper. Because my custom api response wrapper doesn't have JsonView defined in them, they don't get returned.

Comment: You could use Jackson Mix-in's to apply the `@JsonView` annotations to getters.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8477588/1073826

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my jackson addon. I developed it exactly for this purpose.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

Answer (score 0):

I have come across one solution which works, but requires the creation of a new object for my Recipes, a kind of RecipeSummary object.

http://glennpaulley.ca/conestoga/2015/05/jpa-and-native-sql-queries-part-deux/

It uses @SqlResultSetMapping to map a query to a none-entity class.